# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 ... 18) ends beyond length 6

Tags: android

i'm just using `EditText` with token auto complete view and i want the `EditText` input type to be "phone"
so i used..

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     completionView.setPrefix("To: ");
     completionView.addObject(people[0]);
     completionView.addObject(people[1]);     
 }
 onClick();
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
 completionView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

it's not working.. need help....thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe you should post more codes. I don't know what's your real problem and what's your completionView

Comment: what is *completionView* and what contains *people*? But i can tell you that you have "*java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 … 18) ends beyond length 6*" because your text length is 6 (you have 6 characters) and you are trying to set span from 4th to 18th character so you have the "IndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: @Jerome..completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);

Comment: @Rami..people contains{"name","9983423555"}

Comment: i just want my edit text for token complete textview

Comment: @Rami...its working fine for (inputtype.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)

Comment: @Jerome..that is my edit text...i just want the keypad to be number type for user...i m trying this...it works when i clear(backspace) all the token or the very first token it shows this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using [this library](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete), I didn't get any crash though.

```
people = new Person[]{
            new Person("Margaret Smith", "8888888888888"),
            new Person("Max Jordan", "77777777777"),
            new Person("Meg Peterson", "666666666666"),
            new Person("Amanda Johnson", "555555555555"),
            new Person("Terry Anderson", "4444444444444")
    };

    adapter = new FilteredArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.person_layout, people) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = (View)l.inflate(R.layout.person_layout, parent, false);
            }
            Person p = getItem(position);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getName());
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.email)).setText(p.getEmail());
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean keepObject(Person obj, String mask) {
            mask = mask.toLowerCase();
            return obj.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask) || obj.getEmail().toLowerCase().startsWith(mask);
        }
    };
    completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
    completionView.setTokenListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        completionView.setPrefix("To: ");
        completionView.addObject(people[0]);
        completionView.addObject(people[1]);
    }
    completionView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

you should make your question more clear and post the details.

Comment: @Jerome...exactly...their will be one remove last button..what is my actual problem is when i delete the last token either by remove button or backspace on keypad... app get crash..

Comment: @Jerome..thank you so much bro....but removing the last token shows error when i set the type to TYPE_CLASS_PHONE...shows error at set span..need help